# Pass by reference, errors with different base types

Tags: c, visual-studio, reference

Im getting an error that is really frustrating me in my C program.

the error is:

```
main.c(65): error C2371: 'extractVals' : redefinition; different basic types
```

directClass is suppose to accept a reference to a char, specifically line 20 (in the switch case 'g') using variable s. Im not sure how they are not the same basic type, but im not very good with C, so im not great at identifying all issues. Any help would be great.

```
#include <gl\glew.h>
#include <gl\freeglut.h>
#include <gl\GLU.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void directFile(char input[100]){
    char switchVal [10] , *s = switchVal;
    float val1, val2, val3, val4;

    s = strtok(input, " \n\0");

    printf("Told str is %s\n", s);
    switch(*s){

        case '#':
            printf("%s is a comment. Has no bearing on application\n", s);
            break;
        case 'g':
            printf("%s is the command to translate an object!\n", s);
            extractVals(s);
            break;
        case 's':
            printf("%s is the command to scale, now which one is it?\n",s);
            break;
        case 'r':
            printf("%s will rotate the image!\n",s);
            break;
        case 'c':
            if(strcmp(s , "cone") == 0){
                printf("It appears you have your self a %s\n", s);
            } else if (strcmp(s , "cube") == 0){
                printf("%s is cool too\n" , s);
            } else if (*s == 'c'){
                printf("Welp command was \"%s\", lets change some colors huh?\n",s);
            }
            break;
        case 't':
            break;
        case 'o':
            break;
        case 'f':
            break;
        case 'm':
            break;
    }
}

void extractVals(char *input){
    while(input != NULL){
        printf("%s\n", input);
        input = strtok(NULL, " ,");
    }

}

void makeLower(char *input)
{
    while (*input != '\0')
    {
        *input = tolower(*input);
        input++;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char linebyline [50], *lineStr = linebyline;
    char test;

    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    while(!feof(file) && file != NULL){
        fgets(lineStr , 50, file);
        makeLower(lineStr);
        printf("%s",lineStr);

        directFile(lineStr);

    }
    fclose(file);


    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: why it is giving redefinition error is strange, it should give an error something like: 'function extractVals not found'. You are calling a function before it is actually declared.

Comment: C does not support pass-by-reference, but C++ does. C uses pointers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is because you did not provide a prototype before calling `extractVals()`. When the compiler runs into such a case, it assumes that the function is declared like:

```
int extractVals();
```

Then later when it finds the definition, it conflicts with this assumption. This error can be fixed by adding an appropriate prototype, either before `directFile()` or in a header that you include:

```
void extractVals(char *input);
```

Comment: If you increase your warning level `-Wall` the compiler will warn you on the FIRST occasion it encounters extractVals, and you will avoid confusion.

Comment: oh. How simple. Ive been doing too much java!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the compiler is confused because the first time it sees the function extractVals is in the function directFile. The compiler is most likely then assuming the function is (int) blah ( char *). Then when it gets down to your definition of the function it is different, the compiler then throws an error. Although I would have thought this would throw a redefinition of a function error not a basic type.

Either way try adding a prototype of the function at the top of the file

```
void extractVals(char *input); // I let the compiler know that a function with this signature is coming later

void directFile(char input[100]){
char switchVal [10] , *s = switchVal;
float val1, val2, val3, val4;
...
```